# Рулетка на js html

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть рулетка, как сделать так, чтобы оно корректно останавливалось? Все перепробовал что знаю, не получилось.

```html
<style>
.roulette-inner img{
   width:72px;
   height:72px;
   margin:2px;
 }

 .roulette-inner img.active{
   border:2px solid rgba(89,0,153,.2);
   box-sizing:border-box;
   border-radius:50%;
   padding:-4px 4px 2px 4px;
   transform:scale(1.7);
   z-index:1000;
   background-color:rgba(0,255,127,.5);
 }
 </style>
 
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
 jQuery.easing['easeOutCirc'] = function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        return c * Math.sqrt(1 - (t=t/d-1)*t) + b;
    }
$(function() {
    var option = {
        speed: 6,
        duration: 3,
        stopImageNumber: 4
    };

 $("#go").click(function() {
    option.stopImageNumber = Math.random() * 5|0;
    $(".roulette-inner  img").removeClass("active");
    $("#config").text(JSON.stringify(option));
    $({
        left: 0
    }).animate({
        left: 400 * option.speed + 75 * (option.stopImageNumber + 5)
    }, {
        duration: option.duration * 1000,
        easing: "easeOutCirc",
        step: function(a) {
            $(".roulette-inner").css("transform", "translateX(-" + a % 400 + "px)");
        },
        complete: function() {
            $(".roulette-inner  img").eq(option.stopImageNumber + (option.stopImageNumber < 5) * 11).addClass("active");
        }
    });
  })
});
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Config: <span id="config"></span></h2>
<div class="roulette" style="overflow: hidden; height: 126px; width: 844px;">
<div class="roulette-inner" style="position: relative; top: 24px; width: 7000px;">
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/21/13/55/figure-1-3246773_960_720.png" style="display: block; float: left;">
<img src="https://номернедели.рф/gfx/200x200/2.png" style="display: block; float: left;">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/25/NYCS-bull-trans-3.svg/1200px-NYCS-bull-trans-3.svg.png" style="display: block; float: left;">
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" style="display: block; float: left;">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/78/NYCS-bull-trans-5.svg/1200px-NYCS-bull-trans-5.svg.png" style="display: block; float: left;">
</div>
</div>
<button id="go" onclick="play()">Go</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "корректно останавливалось"?

Comment: а вы запустите код. у меня выпадает число, а оно мимо проматывается выпавшего числа.

Comment: А вы сами его запускали? Картинки не отображаются

Comment: а вижу теперь. обновил стили на CTRL F5

Comment: Странно, я пробовал в нескольких браузерах и нигде не отображаются.

Comment: теперь работаю. посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Comment: при остановке на выпавшей цифре, она выделяется, работает через раз, ибо не всегда останавливается где нужно. что делать?

Comment: Лучше добавьте эту информацию в вопрос, так будет нагляднее

Comment: все равно останавливается не там где нао.

Comment: например когда выпадает 0

Comment: Заметьте, когда, например, выпадает 1, то она уезжает за экран, на её месте стоит 2. Значит, нужно всего-то к прокрутке прибавлять или от неё отнимать ширину одного числа (блока с картинкой)